# Passing an index path through an action sheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiactionsheet

I have a table view controller and when you select a row an action sheet appears. Then the user would select an option, followed by `-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` been called. But by that point I don't know which table view cell was selected to bring up the action sheet in the first place. Is there a way to pass an index path through an action sheet?

Answer (score 0):

As UIActionsheet is child of UITableView  you can use tag property to store the indexPath.Row.

I am assuming that your table has only one section. But if your table has more than one section then you can either make 2 class level variable to preserve the indexPath.row and indexPath.column OR you can customize UIActionSheet and assign respective value to properties of your action sheet class.

customizing action sheet will help you even when your tableViewDelegate and action sheet delegate are different.

Please post if you need help in writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Save the index path while displaying action sheet and then click on clickedButtonAtIndex of your action sheet

```
[yourTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:savedIndexPath animated:YES  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
```

which will select your row.
Here **savedIndexPath** is your last selection of your table view